I am getting the foillowing error with Ansible Playbook FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n",
- name: Basic Setup
  hosts: all  ## run on all hosts
  gather_facts: false
  become: true   ## means become sudo or superuser
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  tasks:
    - name: Wait 200 seconds for port 22 to become open and contain "OpenSSH"
      ansible.builtin.wait_for:
        port: 22
        host: "{{ (ansible_ssh_host|default(ansible_host))|default(inventory_hostname) }}"
        search_regex: OpenSSH
        delay: 10
        timeout: 200
      vars:
        ansible_connection: local

    - name: Set a hostname
      ansible.builtin.hostname:
        name: "{{ node_hostname }}"

    - name: Copy /etc/hosts template
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        backup: true
        src: ./files/hosts
        dest: /tmp/hosts

    - name: Insert/Update configuration using a local file and validate it
      ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
        block: "{{ lookup('file', './files/hosts') }}"
        path: /etc/hosts
        backup: yes

    - name: Disable swap on all nodes
      ansible.builtin.shell: swapoff -a

    - name: kernel module prerequesites
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: |
          cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/k8s.conf
          overlay
          br_netfilter
          EOF

    - name: add overlay module
      community.general.modprobe:
        name: overlay
        state: present

    - name: add br_netfilter module
      community.general.modprobe:
        name: br_netfilter
        state: present

    - name: sysctl params required by setup
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        cmd: |
          cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf
          net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables  = 1
          net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
          net.ipv4.ip_forward                 = 1
          EOF

    - name: apply sysctl params without reboot
      ansible.builtin.shell: sysctl --system

    - name: create containerd config file
      ansible.builtin.shell: mkdir -p /etc/containerd && touch /etc/containerd/config.toml

    - name: Install containerd pre-reqs
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        pkg:
          - apt-transport-https
          - ca-certificates
          - curl
          - gnupg
          - lsb-release

    - name: add docker GPG key
      apt_key:
        url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
        state: present

    - name: Add Docker Repository
      apt_repository:
        repo: deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy stable
        state: present

    - name: Update apt and install docker-ce
      apt:
        name: docker-ce
        state: latest
        update_cache: true

    - name: Install containerd.io
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        pkg:
          - containerd.io

    - name: Enable containerd
      ansible.builtin.systemd:   ## it is like doing "sudo systemctl enable containerd"
        name: containerd
        daemon_reload: yes
        state: started
        enabled: yes

    - name: Setup containerd to use systemd as cgroup
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        backup: true
        src: ./files/containerd-config.toml
        dest: /etc/containerd/config.toml

    - name: Restart service cron, in all cases, also issue daemon-reload to pick up config changes
      ansible.builtin.systemd:
        state: restarted
        daemon_reload: yes
        name: containerd

    ## NOTE: kubeadm stuff
    - name: Download Google Cloud's public key
      ansible.builtin.apt_key:
        url: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
        state: present

    - name: Add kubernetes repo
      ansible.builtin.apt_repository:
        repo: deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
        state: present
        filename: kubernetes

    - name: Install kubadm, kubectl, kubelet
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        pkg:
          - kubelet
          - kubeadm
          - kubectl

    - name: hold kubectl,kubeadm,kubelet packages
      ansible.builtin.shell: apt-mark hold kubelet kubectl kubeadm

- name: Setup Control Plane Node
  hosts: master
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: init kubeadm
      ansible.builtin.shell: sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --control-plane-endpoint "{{ansible_host}}:6443" ## here we specify --control-plane-endpoint because we want to advertise our mster node using the  public ip of master node

    - name: create ~/.kube directory
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: ~/.kube
        state: directory
        mode: "0755"

    - name: copy kubeconfig file
      shell: sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config

    - name: set the correct permission on kubeconfig file
      shell: sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

    - name: install flannel
      ansible.builtin.shell: kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flannel-io/flannel/v0.20.2/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml

    - name: Copy kubeconfig file locally ## We copy the kubeconfig file locally to our machine because the kubeconfig file create above lives inside of ec2 instances and if we want to interacewt with the cluster locally we save the kubeconfigfile locally to our machine.
      ansible.builtin.fetch:
        src: $HOME/.kube/config
        dest: /tmp/kubeconfig/
        flat: yes

    - name: Generate join token for worker nodes
      ansible.builtin.shell: sudo kubeadm token create --print-join-command
      register: join_node_token

    - name: Save join command as variable
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        join_node: "{{ join_node_token.stdout_lines[0] }}"

- name: Setup Worker Nodes
  hosts: workers
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: add worker nodes to cluster
      shell: "sudo {{ hostvars['control_plane'].join_node }}"

here is the ansible playbook file.
I do not understand what i am missing
i have access to the private key file

Your user needs to be able to elevate to root without a password or you need to provide the password to sudo via the --ask-become-pass option on the command prompt.

This is more of a linux question, but your ansible user generally should have an entry like this in /etc/sudoers. This would give that user sudo permissions without the need for a password.
ansible_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

On AWS's EC2 servers you will see this in /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users.
